# How to send multiple bitmap images to the server

Tags: android

I want to send the multiple images to server.I have created the bitmap for each selected images.But the last bitmap image are send to the server.How to send all bit map images at once in android.I have tried like this

```
     class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String sResponse = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Room_addroom1.this, "Uploading",
                    "Please wait...", true);
            dialog.show();
        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                String url ="http://airbnb.abservetech.com/demo/public/mobile/hotel/roomsadd";
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                int i=0;
                mImageIds = new ArrayList<String>();
                ByteArrayBody mImageByteArray = null;
                for ( i = 0; i < ImgData.size(); i++) {


                    Log.d("ImgData(i)--", String.valueOf(ImgData.get(i)));

                    Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(ImgData.get(i));

                    String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
                    mImageIds.add(image);
                    Log.d("Image--", image);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                    byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


                     mImageByteArray = new ByteArrayBody(byteArray, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    entity.addPart("room_images", mImageByteArray);
                    Log.d("ByteArray--", String.valueOf(mImageByteArray));
                  //  entity.addPart("room_images", mImageByteArray);
            }
                Log.d("ByteArray-out--", String.valueOf(mImageByteArray));

              /*  entity.addPart("room_images", new ByteArrayBody(byteArray,
                        "image/jpeg", params[1]));*/

                entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("52"));
                entity.addPart("room_type",new StringBody( "premium"));
                entity.addPart("room_prize", new StringBody("2356"));

                httpPost.setEntity(entity);

//                String entityContentAsString = new String(bos.toByteArray());
//                Log.e("multipartEntitty:", "" + entityContentAsString);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                entity.writeTo(bytes);

                String content = bytes.toString();
                String content1 = entity.toString();
         /*       Log.e("MultiPartEntityRequest:",content);
                Log.e("MultiPartEntity---11:",content1);*/
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                        localContext);
                sResponse = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());

                System.out.println("sResponse : " + sResponse);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

            }
            return sResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
            try {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

                if (sResponse != null) {

                    count++;
                    if (count <ImgData.size()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                sResponse + " Photo uploaded successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "hm" + count
//                                + ".jpg");
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not sending bitmaps. You are sending png images.

Comment: Why are you making bitmaps from files? From jpg files? To convert them to png? If you want png then it is ok. Otherwise why dont you directly upload the jpg's?

Comment: I don't know how to upload it in correct format

Comment: What do you consider to be 'the correct format'? Please be clear.

Comment: `String image = getStringImage(bitmap);`. Unclear what is in the string. What is that function doing? What are youi sending exactly?

Answer (score 0):

First you can create bitmap to base64.
then create jsonstring of these all base64 String of bitmap and send JsonString to post the server.
That's easy wat to send multiple image to server.

Another way,
When you select first image then you create base64 of these image at a time you send base64 to server, then select another image and convert to base64 and send another base64 to server. That method also use for one by one image store to server.

Comment: I have uploading these images during room create.So i want to upload multiple images along with other details of room.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mImageIds = new ArrayList<String>();
for ( i = 0; i < ImgData.size(); i++) {


            Log.d("ImgData(i)--", String.valueOf(ImgData.get(i)));
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(ImgData.get(i));

            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
            mImageIds.add(image);
            Log.d("Image--", image);



                    entity.addPart("images", new StringBody(image));

        }
```

The only thing you were doing wrong was you were intializing a new object of the ArrayList for every iteration of the for loop. So, only the last element was being added to the ArrayList. Moving it outside will solve your problem.

Comment: I want to pass inside the entity like this entity.addPart("images", new StringBody(image)); or entity.addPart("images", new StringBody(""+mImageIds)); @Aman Grover

Comment: look at my updated answer for a better understanding of what you were doing wrong and how it will solve your problem

Comment: if i upload StringBody(image) like this means then array list creation is not necessary am i right

Comment: yes you are correct, but depends what you are doing inside StringBody method.

Comment: inside the stringbody i have passed only the image bit map as string

Comment: I still dont understand what problem you are facing. Post the code for StringBody method and code where you are uploading to server. Then only someone might be able to help you

Comment: I'm having another doubt if i pass the image as ByteArrayBody rather than stringbody same last image only upload why? I have update my coading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122718/discussion-between-abserve-tech-and-aman-grover).

Comment: `entity.addPart("images", new StringBody(image));`. Even if you do that a hundred times only the last one will reside in entity  part "images"`. Only one will be send.

Comment: Then what to do for sending whole image @greenapps

Comment: What do you mean with 'whole image'? You wanted to send several images. I told you that only the last one will be send under item name 'images'.

Comment: then any other alternative way to send multiple image dude

Comment: Other alternative way? Until now you have not one way yet. And i told you already that you can attach only one image under entity part 'images'. So now you know what to do: use names only once. If you have different images than use different names. `image1, image2, image3, ...`

Comment: Also possible: `images[0], images[1], images[2], ...`. All depends on your server script. It depends on what your server expects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122726/discussion-between-abserve-tech-and-greenapps).

Comment: Please post your questions here.